# Overlapping Stroke Anchor Points Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, stroke

I'm having trouble getting rid of these criss crossing anchor points in Illustrator. They're on the same path, but the anchor point is creating an extended path and thus a "criss cross".

The odd thing is that the mirrored left side doesn't have this issue.

Any thoughts?

Problem looks like:

[image: problem]

Should look like:

[image: corect]

Comment: What would be the danger of simply deleting one?

Comment: Is this a single path or a shape? The issue looks like a common issue with miter limits and expanded strokes. I've never seen that issue with a single path.

Answer (score 2):

Double check you only have one point at the tip of the path. It's possible there's a couple or more points sitting on top of another. Pathfinder and other object operations can cause these types of problems.

[image]

The example above is pretty rough, but the theory stands — some stray points can cause unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc's answer, another thing to try would be to expand the appearance of the stroke (in the edit menu I believe). This will convert the stroke to a filled object, making removing those additional points easy.